# PDF inside a div -bootstrap well

Tags: php, html, pdf, pdfobject

I've been trying to create a pdfview.php page that would hold separate .pdf files to view. Currently, I'm trying to just make sure that a pdf shows up properly at least. 
I'm using PDFObject for this purpose

Here's the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    window.onload = function () {
        var success = new PDFObject({ url: "/uploads/noor2.pdf" }).embed("pdf");

    };
</script>
```

and for the place holder is just a div

```
<div  id="pdf" class=" well col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 col-xl-8">
    <p> pdf review should be here! </p>
</div>
```

Comment: The examples they provide on their page work without issue for me. So question is what you missed in your adaptation. Please open your browsers development console, reload the embedding page and check for: 1. js errors in the console tab and 2. network errors in the network tab.

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding, i'm getting 5 errors that saying "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 "

Comment: OK, so you found the cause. http status 404 means: not found. So most likely your links are wrong. Take care to check each reference you make and to fix it. The references must point to where the referenced objects (files) are actually offered. Compare the url requested in your browsers console's network tab (where you see the error) with the location where you would expect the objects to be found. This is basic web programming, it has nothing to do with that pdf library.

Comment: Yes, I actually noticed that once you told me to use the console. Thank you so much :) I just haven't had much of sleep lately

Comment: OK, happens, no worries. May I give you a hint? Sleep :-)